# Python + Selenium + Webscraping slow

Tags: python, selenium

```
print ('Page Loaded')

myelem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'inlineListRow')]")


with open("systext.csv","wb") as f:    
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for myinfo in myelem:
        anotherlist = []
        itemize = myinfo.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[contains(@class, 'inlineListBodyCell')]")
        for peritem in itemize:
            anotherlist.append(peritem.text)
        writer.writerows([anotherlist]) 

            for peritem in itemize:
                anotherlist.append(peritem.text)
            writer.writerows([anotherlist])
```

Im trying to extract info from a website then, write it to a csv 
i get all elements then get each element's sub element

the code i got works

Problem is that it takes 10+ mins to complete my loop is that normal or 
is my code not efficient for the task

Data is 13 col by 1800 Rows total size is a 400kb

Comment: Scope inside "for myinfo in myelem:" you can do asynchronous. And why you repeat and nest "for peritem in itemize:" - it is inefficient.

Comment: Im just starting out, can you please elaborate your first sentence.

im gonna try your second statement. i thought that i have to seperate td elements of tr element 1 by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whole code but it should be something like:

```
print('Page Loaded')

myelem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'inlineListRow')]")

async def iterate(w, info):
    anotherlist = []
    itemize = info.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[contains(@class, 'inlineListBodyCell')]")
    for peritem in itemize:
        anotherlist.append(peritem.text)
        # if in this nested loop by anotherlist you meant anotherlist2 otherwhise remove it
        # anotherlist2.append(peritem.text)
    # writer.writerows([anotherlist2])
    w.writerows([anotherlist])
    return

with open("systext.csv","wb") as f:    
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for myinfo in myelem:
        iterate(writer, myinfo)
```

Comment: async def iterate returns an error
it worked perfectly once i remove async
so thank you. ill mark as answer.
however i would really appreciate if you could tell me how that speed up my code. 
as far as i could i understand you created a function outside of the loop doing the same thing.

Comment: Which version of python do you use? In 3.6 it should work, but for older versions you need to use asyncore and asynchat modules.